# restore attach sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server

My old computer crashed and died a couple of weeks ago(motherboard), and I have been able to copy data from the hard drive over to new computer.

Problem is with sql database, I'm not able to restore or attach as I get the error access is denied
Anybody have an idea as to what I can do.

Thanks
George

Comment: Hey, can you tell us what sql server edition this is and ideally provide the exact error message you're getting.  The pre-edit  version suggests file permissions issues and it now suggests login issues so more detail would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to get data via attach/restore, I just went into the data folder and copied and pasted the old db and log files, now works OK.